# How to save bytes to file as binary mode

Tags: python-3.x, codec

I have a bytes-like object something like:

```
aa = b'abc\u6df7\u5408def.mp3'
```

I want to save it into a file in binary mode. the codes are below, but not work well

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    aa = b'abc\u6df7\u5408def.mp3'
    print(aa.decode('unicode-escape'))

    with open('database.bin', "wb") as datafile:
        datafile.write(aa)
```

the data in file is like that:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCu6i.png)

but i want the right format is like this, unicodes in binary data:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZoyK.png)

How can i convert the bytes to save it in file?

Comment: first step, we can convert aa to bb = b'abc\\xf7\\x6d\\x08\\x54def.mp3', then datafile.write(bb). but how to do that?

Comment: Your input is not what you hope it to be. It seems like you want `aa = 'abc\u6df7\u5408def.mpi'.encode('utf-8')` to initialize the byte string. The byte string `b\\u'` is simply `b'\\'` (backslash) followed by `b'u'` (byte string with lowercase letter `u`).

Comment: change aa to aa = b'abc\u6df7\u5408def.mp3', the problem still.

Comment: No, `\u` in a byte string isn't well-defined. If you want the UTF-8 encoding of a Unicode string, you have to say so.

Comment: Actually, you seem to want `utf-16be` but the rest still applies trivially.

Comment: i have a question: is there any difference between b'abc\u6df7\u5408def.mp3' and b'abc\xf7\x6d\x08\x54def.mp3'? And How to convert from one to another?

Comment: One of them is not well-defined. To convert from a string to a byte string, `encode` using the encoding you want. To go the other way, `decode`; then, you obviously have to know (or guess correctly) the encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\uNNNN` escapes do not make sense in byte strings because they do not specify a sequence of bytes. Unicode code points are conceptually abstract representations of strings, and do not straightforwardly map to a serialization format (consisting of bytes, or, in principle, any other sort of concrete symbolic representation).

There *are* well-defined serialization formats for Unicode; these are known as "encodings". You seem to be looking for the UTF-16 big-endian encoding of these characters.

```
aa = 'abc\u6df7\u5408def.mp3'.encode('utf-16-be')
```

With that out of the way, I believe the rest of your code should work as expected.

Unicode on disk is *always* encoded but you obviously have to know the encoding in order to read it correctly. An optional [byte-order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) is sometimes written to the beginning of serialized Unicode text files to help the reader discover the encoding; this is a single non-printing character whose sole purpose is to help disambiguate the encoding, and in particular its byte order (big-endian vs little-endian).

However, many places are standardizing on UTF-8 which doesn't require a BOM. The encoding itself is byte-oriented, so it is immune to byte order issues. Perhaps see also https://utf8everywhere.org/